# Open .rdl files with Report Builder (2016) by default (Sql Server)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

My computer has decided this morning that any .rdl file will be opened in Visual Studio, rather than the Report Builder that designed them and I have been unable to find a way to change the default program back, normally I would use the open with function, however the application does not appear. looking at where the shortcut goes, this refers to some unknown location (basically not directing to a C:/ folder)

has anyone encountered this issue before and if so, how can i set all RDL files to open up using the 2016 SSRS Report Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the approach listed [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2016/08/11/opening-sql-files-in-ssms-2016-by-default-sqlnewblogger/). This explains the trick for .sql files, but the approach is the same.

In short:

- Go to `Default app settings` in Windows
- Scroll to `.rdl`-files
- The icon probably shows Visual Studio now, click on it and go to the location where Report Builder is installed and select the `Prorb32.exe`.

Comment: that worked a treat, I would never of thought of doing that! cheers